# Saving self-written code - xtend

Tags: code-generation, xtend

I want to know if it is possible to save self-written code within a generated file. If you change the model and then push the save button, all code is overwritten. I want to save some of the code of the old file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtend uses a source generating compiler thus the produced Java code for Xtend itself cannot be altered on the source level.

Nevertheless, if you use Xtend's template expression to generate code, you can of course insert protected regions to allow users to modify the generated code. This OS [project](https://github.com/danieldietrich/xtext-protected-regions) on Github implements support for protected regions in Xtend.

Comment: "Those changes cannot be preserved for obvious reasons. That would be like editing class files manually and trying to convince the Java compiler to keep those changes." Well that is your opinion. You can use xtend for more than just generating those files. I have an area in my generated file that is for self made code and this code needs to be saved.

Comment: Are you refering to code that is produced from a template expression in your Xtend class or are your talking about the Java code in the xtend-gen folder?

Comment: I am talking about the code thats is produces from a template expression in my xtend files. The codegenerations takes place every time one hits the save button in the editor. I heard there is a possibility to tag code that is not overwritten.

Comment: I updated my answer and added a link to https://github.com/danieldietrich/xtext-protected-regions