# Template engine/pre-processor that works from *within* the target language

Tags: eclipse-plugin, preprocessor, code-generation

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE, and I now have looked at about a dozen template engines, and they all seem to work in a similar way:

1. You create a template file in the *template language*
2. The IDE plugin, if any, recognize the *template syntax*, rather then the target language syntax.
3. The generated/modified file, in the target language, is *read-only*, since it will get replaced on next generation.

This greatly limits the use of template engines/pre-processor, because you *loose the IDE support for the target language*.

Generally, the templating syntax will be simple enough anyway, that you could easily get by without IDE support for it. What is really needed, is to get the *target language support* from within the template.

In other words, is there some pre-processor/template engine, that does *not* require you to create "template files", but rather register itself in the IDE between the file system and the target language support, modifying the content of the file on the fly such that the target language plugin sees the file *after generation*, while the file is saved in the file system as it was *before the generation*, that is, it contains the template on the file system, rather then the generated code.

In *other* other words, I want to write the templates in the *target language*, and have them recognized as such by the IDE editor, such that the editor sees the code *after generation* (maybe hide the template instructions in comments?).

Such a plugin would then be totally generic, and independent of the actual file type containing the template (as long as it's a text file). All that would be needed, is then some configuration file telling the template engine in which files/directories to look for templates.

Alternatively, if no such product exist, does it seem like something that *could* be implemented in Eclipse as a plugin, or is it more a case that there are no such plugin *because it would be basically impossible*?

Here a list of a few things I've looked at, all of which don't seem to support the desired use case:

- [Xtend](http://blog.efftinge.de/2013/06/five-good-reasons-to-port-your-code.html)
- [eclipseME - Preprocessing](http://eclipseme.org/docs/preprocessing.html)
- [Java Comment Preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/)
- [Preprocessing Java with Munge](http://blog.publicobject.com/2009/02/preprocessing-java-with-munge.html) [Munge](https://www.java.net//blog/tball/archive/munge/Munge.java)
- [Velocity](http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/)
- [Jamon](http://www.jamon.org/Eclipse.html)
- [JET](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html)
- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [Xpand](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xpand)
- [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/editors.html)
- [Mustache Java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)
- [Jade4J](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j)
- [Closure Templates in Java](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/java_usage?hl=de)
- [Rythm Engine](http://rythmengine.org/)

Related question: [Saving self-written code - xtend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263790/saving-self-written-code-xtend)

Comment: You're not correct on JET.  You can identify regions of generated text that can be modified after generation and for which those changes are kept across subsequent regenerations.  As for the JET templates, they are generally in the target language, but with markups to perform the generation.  I don't think you're going to find what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are referring to something like this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET2/jet_tutorial2.html#typesafe_enum_template It comes close, but as you say, it's not quite what I was looking for. I found that "Xtext Protected Regions" as mentioned in the linked question, also come close, but also not quite it.